How does correlation impact parameter estimation?
I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of how the kalman filter is able to update variables indirectly during the measurement process.
Suppose we have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$ with covariance matrix $K$ but with unknown means and suppose we are able to repeatedly sense $X$, so we can do some form of estimation procedure.
How can extract an approximate mean for $Y$ only using the correlation information?

Looking at this more, it doesn't appear to be possible. The reason is that for example, the Gaussian distribution has separate mean and covariance, meaning any two means produce a valid Gaussian.
